# integrating ebay authentication in django application

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a django application in which user will be able to sign up or sign in only via their EBay account, no email/username or password required. I couldn't find any authentication library for EBay though there are many for google, facebook, twitter etc.

So I got the EBay part working. EBay basically returns (on consent of user) Email and a IEFS token which is unique to that user and wont change. I want to use those two fields only to create a authenticate user across whole application. I don't want username, emails, firstname, lastname or password that ships with django User model. The documentation is quite big and I am confused where to start, any proper suggestion will be big help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of insight, the code is yours to make :

- You can extend the user model from Django and decide which field to use, you could for example create a Ebay ID field [Abstract User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/)
- Once this is done you want to add the ebay ID to an user, just create an account with email and ID, the user won't need any more info
- Finally allow user to connect only by email, either by overriding custom login from Django or using a package like [Django Allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Please note that unless your site is accessible only by Ebay users, allowing user to connect with email/password is recommended.

It is perfectly doable, just make good use of the documentation

Comment: thanks, I got desired model using abstract user